# How to use multiple variables in "subprocess.run" function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, subprocess

i hava a small python3 code.
I want to use multiple variables in subprocess.run

```
import subprocess

scripts_home='/usr/local/bin'
script_argument = 'argument'

def function():
    subprocess.run("script_home/script.sh %s" % script_argument, shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout
```

how can i use script_home variable in command ?

I will already tried:

```
subprocess.run("%s/script.sh %s" % script_home % script_argument, shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: `'%s some string %s' % (s1, s2)`. But use f-strings or `.format()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string specifiers are not correct in your implementation.

Try the following line:

```
subprocess.run("{script_home}/script.sh {script_args}".format(script_home=script_home, script_args=script_argument), shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout
```

Comment: Thank for answer, its worked !

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass in the arguments as a list instead.

```py
import subprocess

scripts_home='/usr/local/bin'
script_argument = 'argument'

def function():
    return subprocess.run(
        [f"{script_home}/script.sh", script_argument],
        capture_output=True).stdout
```

Notice how `shell=True` is no longer necessary or useful (or correct) with this change.

See also [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

(And I guess you forgot the `return` in front. Without that, your function simply returns `None`.)

There are many different ways to produce the first string here.

```
script_home + '/script.sh'     # string addition is pretty inefficient and ugly
'%s/script.sh' % script_home   # legacy Python 2.x, fugly %
'{0}/script.sh'.format(script_home)
f'{script_home}/script.sh'     # f-string, Python 3.6+
```